# C# - Calling private function when building Predicate not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, predicate, predicatebuilder

We're trying to build a predicate thanks to a PredicateBuilder helper class when calling Entity Framework Core:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<Formulaire>(form => GetFormulaireProgressStatus(form) != Enums.FormStatus.NotStarted);
```

Here's the content of GetFormulaireProgressStatus(form):

```
    private Enums.FormStatus GetFormulaireProgressStatus(Formulaire instanciated)
    {
        if (!instanciated.FormHistoryRelay.Any())
        {
            return FormStatus.NotStarted;
        }
        if (instanciated.FormReported.Any())
        {
            return FormStatus.Closed;
        }
        return FormStatus.Started;
    }
```

The outcome of this : the child FormHistoryRelay is always empty even though we're calling:
dbContext.Formulaire.Include(i => i.FormHistoryRelay).Where(predicate);

We even tried to convert from Expression<Func<T, V>> into Func<T, V> using Invoke() method available in PredicateBuilder but it's still the same result :(

Are we missing something ? In case you're asking, the version of **EFCore** used at the moment is **2.1.14**.
Thanks for your help guys in advance !

Comment: If `FormHistoryRelay` is always empty then the `Include` isn't working and your issue is not related to the expression.

Comment: No the FormHistoryRelay should always have at least one element (that's how the application works) that's why it's can't be empty :S

Comment: Yeah, but it *is* empty, as you say yourself.